# Get Toolbar (v7) current colors

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I change toolbar color programatically by setting:

```
setBackgroundColor(color_bg);
setTitleTextColor(color_text);
```

How do i get back these colours (current colours)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really simple call `toolbar.getBackgroundColor()` and you get the current color of the toolbar.